# Pass parameter to MVC PHP controller and open new page without submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twig

I have a page with images. In every image, there is a onClick event and a id to see detail of that recipe. When you click, it goes via AJAX to the action in the controller, that makes a new view with Twig. The problem is that it doesn't reload (not submit button), and when i assign the response to html, the menus at the beginning of the new page don't work. And, in addition, doesn't change the URL (only if I make that tricky window.history.pushState, and doesn't work going history back until you refresh page)

HTML

```
<img src="{{recipe.image}}" onclick="showDetail()" id={{recipe.id}}>
```

JS

```
function showDetail() {
  var detailId = $(event.target).attr('id');
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "showDetail",
    dataType: "html",
    data: {id:detailId},
    success: function(res){
      // $("html").html(res); // this one makes menus don't work
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ $("#respRecipe").html(textStatus + ' ' + jqXHR.status + ' ' + errorThrown); }
  });
```

Controller

```
public function showDetailAction($params) {
    $model = new DetailModel;
    $recipeData = $model->recipeDataDB($params["id"]);
    View::renderTwig('Detail/detail.html', array('recipeData'=>$recipeData[0],
    'ingredientsData'=>$recipeData[1], 'commentsData'=>$recipeData[2]));
}
```

routes.json (Can i change this one to accept parameters without needing AJAX?)

```
"showDetail": {
    "controller": "DetailController",
    "action": "showDetail"
 },
```

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\/]*)$ index.php?p=$1

</IfModule>
```

I don't know if I can but a hidden submit button inside the image... The main problems are to refresh page, the url and working menus.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that it doesn't reload (not submit button), and when i
>   assign the response to html, the menus at the beginning of the new
>   page don't work.

with Ajax call, page do not reload. Ajax is suppose to make a request and get the response without reload

> And, in addition, doesn't change the URL (only if I make that tricky
>   window.history.pushState, and doesn't work going history back until
>   you refresh page)

Usually with Ajax we do not change the URL unless we intended to go to different page route.

You can change the contain of the html tag if you are getting the correct response as you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you have a Javascript error somewhere, take a look in the console (F12).

The idea of an AJAX request isn't to reload the page, it's to make a request for information from the server and to be able to work with the data returned, without having to refresh the page. If it is refreshing the page, this is often the fault of a JS error, although, in your case, you're asking for all of the html to be refreshed with `$("html").html(res);`, which isn't ideal.

So, in your AJAX success, try doing something like `$('#myDiv').html(res);`. If you get a successful response from the AJAX call (you could `console.log(res);` to find out), then `<div id="myDiv"></div>` will receive the result. You'll need to add the div to your HTML.

Once you get `<div id="myDiv"></div>` to show the result without refreshing the page, you can send back a much smaller block of HTML than a template consisting of all the HTML for the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing a container inside a page and load data returned from AJAX.
The statement `$("html").html(res);`replaces whole content returned from AJAX response instead use some div which loads the result `$("div#YOURID").html(res);`

Need further details as perhaps your your menu need some jQuery initialization etc.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! I created a cookie that expires 5 seconds later. No error in console and the menus are working :)

```
function showDetail() {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + 5000);
  var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = "idRecipe=" + $(event.target).attr("id") + "; " + expires;
  location.href = "detail";
}

public function showDetailAction() {
    $model = new DetailModel;
    $recipeData = $model->recipeDataDB($_COOKIE["idRecipe"]);
    View::renderTwig('Detail/detail.html', array('recipeData'=>$recipeData[0],
    'ingredientsData'=>$recipeData[1], 'commentsData'=>$recipeData[2]));
}
```